# Access position in JavaScript Array with last of particular number

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, datetime, object

I have a websocket open passing me data, the data is an object that includes a time-stamp (of type Date) and a price (of type number).

*** I need to access the last price at the end of every minute. ***

So I've used the .getMinute() method on the Date, this returns the minute.
For example if the Date was 2017-12-14T00:26:19.944Z and the price was 19.99 then I would make an object like this: {time: 26, price: 19.99}

I then push this to an array and the process repeats...
...so I could have an array like so:

```
[{time: 26, price: 19.99}, {time: 26, price: 17.99}, {time: 26, price: 22.45}, {time: 27, price: 25.21}]
```

I need to access the last price for each time property - so above I need to access the price of 22.45 and push it into a new array.

Help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take advantage of the fact that [`objects`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) cannot have duplicate properties of the same name.

See below for a practical example.

Notice the use of a [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function to reach `object form` `{time: price}` and a subsequent [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to return to the original [`array form`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) `[{time, price}..]`.

The result is an `array` containing only the `latest price` of each `minute`.

```js
// Original Data.
const data = [{time: 26, price: 19.99}, {time: 26, price: 17.99}, {time: 26, price: 22.45}, {time: 27, price: 25.21}]

// Object Form.
const unique = data.reduce((accumulator, point) => ({...accumulator, [point.time]: point.price}), {})

// Array Form.
const array = Object.keys(unique).map((time) => ({time, price: unique[time]}))

// Result.
console.log('Object Form', unique) // Object Form.
console.log('Array Form', array) // Array Form.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
let newArr = [timeArr[timeArr.lenght - 1].price]
or
otherArr.push(timeArr[timeArr.lenght - 1].price)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is just return the last element of the array's value

```
let lastPrice = data[data.length - 1].price;
```

Example below

```js
let data = [{time: 26, price: 19.99}, {time: 26, price: 17.99}, {time: 26, price: 22.45}, {time: 27, price: 25.21}]

let lastPrice = data[data.length - 1].price;
console.log(lastPrice);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this simple function should work:

```js
var getLatestTimestamp = function(arr){
    var lastTimestamps = [];
    var l = arr.length -1 ;
     
    lastTimestamps.push(arr[l]);
    for(var i = l; i > 0; i--){
     if(lastTimestamps[lastTimestamps.length -1].time !== arr[i].time) {
      lastTimestamps.push(arr[i]);
     }
    }
    
    return lastTimestamps;
};
    
var arr = [
    {time: 26, price: 19.99}, 
    {time: 26, price: 17.99}, 
    {time: 26, price: 22.45}, 
    {time: 27, price: 25.21},
];
    
var distinctTimestamps = getLatestTimestamp(arr);
    
console.log(distinctTimestamps); 
/* 
[ { time: 27, price: 25.21 }, { time: 26, price: 22.45 } ]
*/
```